# MySQL: automatic rollback on transaction failure

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

Is there any way to set MySQL to rollback any transaction on first error/warning automatically?

Now if everything goes well, it commits, but on failure it leaves transaction open and on another start of transaction it commits incomplete changes from failed transaction. So i need to rollback automatically those failed transactions..

(I'm executing queries from php, but i don't want to check in php for failure, as it would make more calls between mysql server and webserver.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, You are going to need to do this on your own.
I am not a PHP person, but in SQL: If you create a transaction and do several MySQL operations within the transaction, if you rollback the transaction everything will be rolled back. NOTE: You need to be using a transactional storage engine and autocommit must be set to off.

If all you are concerned about is the transaction coordination traffic then you could create a stored procedure and simply call it.

The reason the database does not automatically commit or rollback is because it does not know what you are trying to do, committing some data and rolling back other data might be acceptable in an app.

Comment: Did I form my question so bad? I know how transactions work, I was also asking about mysql solution only, so it's good you are nonPHP person. Please tell me in which part should i make that question more clear.

Comment: @praksant If I did not answer the question with what I wrote, then what are you asking for ?

Comment: I asked if there is a way to rollback AUTOMATICALLY, because it's not the way it works by default. I explained in my question how does it behave by default. I want to eliminate checking in PHP for failure, as it would mean 1-2 calls for every transaction. If it rolled back automatically i would be able to do many transactions in one call what would be a performance boost.

Comment: Thank you for your Update. I need simple logic - if (any error occurred) rollback, else commit. It's very easy in PHP or other language to check after each transaction for error, and commit/rollback accordingly. I just wanted to boost performance. if mysql is on remote machine, every call is very expensive. Stored procedures may do it, but i want greater flexibility in the transactions and maintenance/testing of stored procedures isn't very easy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such feature, but I also don't see how checking for failure would mean more calls:

```
try:
     <my code>
except:
     transaction.rollback()
     raise
else:
     transaction.commit()
```

-- it's in Python/Django, but it should directly transpose to PHP - and it takes exactly the same amount of code to start new transaction, no matter if there is a problem (exception) or not.

Comment: First call is the transaction, second is rollback, and multiply this by number of transactions. I would like to send one file with more transactions, and I want mysql to execute all transactions and rollback any failed ones.

Answer (score 0):

the key point to to set autocommit to false.

```
<?php
$database= new mysqli("sever", "user", "key", "database");
$database->autocommit(FALSE);
$error=0;

//asumming we want to delete a users infomation from two table
$database->query("delete from `pay` where `user`=1 ")?NULL:$error=1;
$database->query("delete from `users` where `id`=1 ")?NULL:$error=1;

if($error=0){
    $database->commit();
}  else {
    $database->rollback();
}
$database->close();
?>
```